# using ogg or mp3 with android?

Tags: android

1.What are the benefits if using oggvorbis over mp3 in android?

2.if  we use ogg vorbis,is it possible to change its header(xor or encryption) and make it unplayble?

regards,
hitendra gohil

Answer (score 1):

The problem is more specific to encryption rather than using ogg or mp3, I had a similar issue where client wants that the downloaded images can only be viewed through his apps, what I applied is I cut the 32 bytes from the beginning of every file and write it database and when I want the resource to be used I pick that 32 bytes and the original file to make usable file at some hidden location.

I hope the point is clear and might help.

Comment: Lol, that works I guess and will get most users. It is not security though but was the client happy and was it what they wanted?

Comment: see in case of mp3 even if i cut more than 1mb still it is playble becase mp3 contains data frame by frame that i have tested but for ogg i dont know that whether it is playble or not after changing header file.

Comment: @ Robert Massaioli Yes this is what the client wanted and to be more clear using this technique will make the content(images) specific to device only that mean if the user share content to some other device having the same app then also he is not able to open it

Comment: @Hitendra Its being a long time I worked on MP3 so cant say anything but you can try for ogg if that works for you also I have just given the idea how I corrupted the file its up to you that you can implement your own killer way to corrupt the file

Comment: @Saurabh Agnihotri  i m able to corrupt the file by xoring and encryption.but my probem is that when i am playing this file ,first i need to decrypt it.it works fine with galaxy tab and htc(takes 4 to 5 sec to decrypt).but in lower configuration device without jit it takes too much time (45 secs) to play song. i need to find some way that encrypted or corrpted file should be start playing with 1 or 2 secs.

Comment: Yes encryption is heavy on performance on lower devices one way to improve the performance is not encrypt the whole file but encrypt few bytes then skip say 200bytes like so